# PHP - Eliminar valores de una variable $_POST con str_replace

Tags: php

Buen dia. Me gustaria eliminar unos valores de una consulta que recibo via POST. tengo una variable $consulta el cual recibe el valor `= SELECT * FROM equipos WHERE () AND (( nombre='computadora' OR nombre='mouse' OR nombre='teclado' )) AND (( departamento='Electronica' ))` donde deseo eliminar los AND vacios `() AND`. De antemano gracias.

Aqui esta mi codigo:

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 $consulta = $_POST["consulta_sql_general"];

 $and_vacios = array('() AND', ' () AND ', 'AND ()', ' AND () '); // 
 expresiones no admitidas

 $consulta1 = str_replace($and_vacios, '', $consulta);
 echo $consulta;

 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_replace` no funciona bien con arrays del modo en que lo intentas usar.

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Ante todo, limpia la cadena de posibles espacios en blanco sobrantes. Se puede fácilmente por error escribir más de un espacio en blanco, y si eso ocurre, tumbaría la lógica del programa. Además, haciendo eso ya no tienes que buscar: `AND ()` y `AND ()`, con que busques `AND ()` bastaría. No obstante, he agregado dos posibles valores erróneos a `$replaceAnds`, que son `AND()` y `()AND`, ya que es un error frecuente olvidar los espacios de separación, sobre todo cuando se concatenan los valores.
- Luego prepara un array de reemplazos explícitos por cada caso.

El código sería este:

```
$consulta = "
                SELECT * FROM equipos WHERE 
                ()  AND (( nombre='computadora' OR nombre='mouse' OR nombre='teclado' )) 
                AND (( departamento='Electronica' ))
                () AND () AND () AND      AND () () AND  ()AND         AND()
             ";

/*Limpiamos la cadena de espacios en blanco sobrantes que podrían darnos muchos problemas*/
$consulta= preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $consulta);;

/*Creamos un array de reemplazos explícito*/
$replaceAnds = array(
'() AND' =>  '',
'AND ()'  => '',
'AND()'  => '',
'()AND'  => '',
);

$resultado = str_replace(array_keys($replaceAnds), $replaceAnds, $consulta);
echo $resultado;
```

Tendrías como resultado:

```
 SELECT * FROM equipos WHERE (( nombre='computadora' OR nombre='mouse' OR nombre='teclado' )) AND (( departamento='Electronica' ))
```

---

> **Nota:**
>
> Posiblemente conviene mejorar la lógica que está produciendo tu
>   consulta, pues no debería crearse así. Deberías implementar una
>   especie de query builder inteligente que sepa cuando crear los `AND` y
>   cuando no.

Comment: WOW Muchas gracias funciona perfectamente

Comment: Me alegro @JulianMartinez. De todos modos, considera lo que digo al final, en la **Nota**. Realmente tu consulta no debería construirse así de mal. Hay lógica para crear un *query builder*  que te cree la SQL correctamente según los datos necesarios. Pero ese es otro asunto. Si te interesa explorar esa posibilidad, puedes plantear el problema en otra pregunta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que utilices **preg_replace** que te permite crear una expresion regular y sustituya lo que cumple con la expresion regular. Algo como esto:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $consulta = $_POST["consulta_sql_general"];

$pattern="/\\s*(AND)*\\s*\\(\\s*\\)\\s*(AND)*/";
$consulta1 = preg_replace($pattern,'',$consulta);

echo $consulta;
 ?>
```

Comment: sigue sin quitar los () AND

Comment: @JulianMartinez,  por favor, pon un ejemplo de una consulta en la que no te funcione, para poder mejorar la expresion regular. Saludos